# Managing Backbone.js Page Transitions

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I know this is a very commonly discussed topic but I can't find anything that answers my question exactly :)

I'm working on a Backbone.js project at the moment. Router wise I don't instantiate views, models or collections within the router but instead just use the router as one way of dealing with state - the router calls methods on my custom controller object.

My controller then instantiates the different views, models and collections for index, show etc. This is all fine and dandy.

I'm just having a bit of a struggle with how to deal with page transitions. I've read all of the great posts on managing zombies etc, and know that whatever happens I have to have some cleanup system for old views (I'm currently using the .close() method that Derick Bailey blogged about).

If I'm going from #show to #index, or any other route **change**, I understand that it makes sense to just instantiate new, fresh views, models, etc - which is what I see in pretty much every tutorial. Making sure to cleanup old ones, of course.

But, if I'm already on #show say, and I route to another #show page, all of the views etc that I want are already instantiated and rendered. All I want to change is the data of the models and collections.

So I guess my question is why do I not see people re-using views very much. In my head I was thinking if you're already on the page that you want, it would make more sense to just update the url or urlRoot of the model / collection that that view is linked to and re-fetch. This would then trigger a reset event, and all views that need to can subscribe to this and re-render themselves.

But, as I say, I don't see people doing this. Is it just because it's a really bad idea? If someone is doing something like this, how do you deal with tracking 'refreshable' models and collections?

Thanks!

Comment: When you render a view, do you pass it a model? If so, just re-call the render function of the view, but pass it a different model. The view doesn't get destroyed, the markup within it is just recreated using the data for the newly passed in model

Comment: What I'm currently working on has a top-level view (the page view, I guess) which is passed a collection and a model (these are instantiated and have their url set based off the router passed parameters within the controller), this top-level view renders in it's skeleton form and a couple of child views - the child views are passed either the collection or model based on what they display and are rendered in (using the model or collection data) also. 

What I'm struggling with I guess is the 'top-level' management. Say we now route off to another page, I can destroy this page and make a new

Comment: one. But say the route 'changes', but realistically it's the same page but with different parameters, is it okay to just change the url / urlRoot of the resources (model, collection) and re-fetch, thus firing events, and re-rendering? 

I know there's 'no right way' with Backbone.js, but I haven't seen what I've described really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends a lot on how you are using your views and how complicated/large they are.

If your views are very simple then it is often just easier to rerender the entire view and replace the existing HTML with the new markup (it might also be faster then traversing the DOM to change the necessary parts. However if you have a more complicated view and there is only a small amount of information changing it is most likely better to listen to the appropate attributes change events (eg. [`_bind('change:name', this.nameChanged,this)`)](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-change) and then only update that part of the DOM.

Keep in mind that while the convention is to use a `render` method which renders the element, you can just as easily apply an additional refresh event to only `refresh` certain parts, you can then just swap models (like @jackwanders suggested) and call the `refresh` method.

Comment: Okay, thanks Jack. I think it's just a case of trial and error then, I'll see how both perform.